# Excel to display graphs by values, not index

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to plot a function (say f(x) = x^2) and some "approximation" points.

So I tried using a first tables with a mesh and corresponding functions values :

```
  X    | x^2
-5.0   | 25
-4.9   | 24.01
...    | ...
 5.0   | 25
```

Then, I have a second table with same range of VALUES (this is the output of the Newton method)

```
  X    | x^2
   3   | 9
  1.5  | 2.25
  0.75 | 0.5625
  ...  | ...
```

Now, is it possible (if so how) to plot the two series on the same graph but having the X axis to consider the X as VALUES and not "Labels". The only result I had so far is to get the second values to be displayed by index (i.e. 9 at index 0, corresponding to -5 in first series) etc...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried using a scatter plot?

Comment: Yep that's it... Cheers !